# Launch App before sending SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

My idea: have an hook to force Android to call a function of my App before an SMS will be sent.

What I want to do is to ask the user (that wrote the SMS using an arbitrary App or the standard App) if he wants to send the SMS using GSM (= normal way) or an other provider over Internet.

Is it possible? I found some information about ContentObserver, but I'm not sure how I can cancel the send of the "normal GSM send" after I sent the SMS via Internet...

Thanks for any help!
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such hook available to call your app function before sending the SMS. You may have to customise Android framework to achieve this.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then, plan B: I'll write an App to send SMS over the IP-Provider and then save them in the SMS-DB. How can I register my App so that the user can choose it for sending messages (as WhatsApp and Hangouts did)? Thank you

Comment: You mean you wanted your app to be available in the share provider list. If so please follow the below steps. http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html